# Best practice for internationalized ng2-translate app angular2

Tags: angular, internationalization, ng2-translate

Hi I have an angular 2 project internationalized with ng2-translate, it works fine but in all my module I have imported translatemodule ecc... So now the app call  selectedLanguage.json in every page clicked.
Is there a way to charge the translation only at the application start?
And maybe to import module only in the root module?

Comment: using ngx-translate instead, https://github.com/ngx-translate/core#usage

Comment: Can you tell me why?

Comment: ngx-translate is newer version of ng2-translate, and it come from same guy, who create ng2-translate, with a lot of bug fixing, and support lazy load better.

Comment: But with ngx can I load translation only 1 time? and not with every page loads?

Comment: you can config using same instance

Answer (score 1):

You problem is most likely that you are importing ng2-translate in a module for every component. So **each component** has it's own copy of ng2-translate and **each instance** is fetching the translations. I would suggests only importing ng2-translate at your root module(app.module.ts) so that you only have one copy shared across your application.